# Unable to select Angular dropdown menu using selenium in python

Tags: python, angular, selenium, automation

A selenium newbie here. I'm trying to use Selenium to automate download of CSV file from calltools and upload it to salesforce. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1ajz.png) is the UI for the dropdown menu for selecting the options before exporting the CSV.

The HTML for the same is:

```
<div _ngcontent-rnw-c215="" style="">
<label _ngcontent-rnw-c215="">Templates</label>

<br _ngcontent-rnw-c215="">

<select _ngcontent-rnw-c215="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
   <option _ngcontent-rnw-c215="" value="0: null"></option>
   <option _ngcontent-rnw-c215="" value="1: Agent KPI" class="ng-star-inserted" 
       style="" xpath="1">Agent KPI</option>
   <option _ngcontent-rnw-c215="" value="2: Payroll" class="ng-star- 
       inserted">Payroll</option>
   <option _ngcontent-rnw-c215="" value="3: Agent Status" class="ng-star- 
       inserted">Agent Status</option>
<!---->
</select>
```

I have tried multiple ways to access the appropriate option (1. Agent KPI). My code so far is

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty']//option[@value='1: Agent KPI']"))
    ).click()
```

The other approach tried is:

```
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@class='ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty']//option[@value='1: Agent KPI']")
```

All these options are resulting in:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@class='ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty']"}
```

But this didn't work either. I used implicit wait as well but I am getting the same error. I checked the HTML and there's no iframe within the same. I have been using selectorhub to retrieve XPATHs of elements so pretty sure they're correct. I also used CSS selectors and tag names but still stuck on the same.

I looked everywhere but despite the various threads and answers, I'm still stuck on this issue. Could anyone advise me on what's going wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are nearly there. If I take the reference of your page element I can see the class name you have provided seems wrong.

Try this below xpath.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched']//option[@value='1: Agent KPI']"))
    ).click()
```

Comment: Thanks for identifying the discrepancy, @KunduK. I tried the same but I'm getting a selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException. I tried changing the timeout period to be 50 instead of 30 but still getting the same error.